# Concat two strings with different links

Tags: javascript, google-docs

I have data in an external table (Spreadsheet) and I am using them to automatize buidling a price list in Google Docs. I am able to pull all data nicely to the table and proper cells but I got stuck on the formating issue.

In one TableCell I need to concat two strings with different formating, somethink like:

```
var text1 = "First text";
text1.getElement().asText();
text1.setLinkUrl(1, text1.length, "http://first");

var text2 = "Second text";
text2.getElement().asText();
text2.setLinkUrl(1, text2.length, "http://second");

tables[0].getRow(0).getCell(0).setText(text1+text2);
```

But evidently this approach does not work. setLinkUrl is an example, I might need to use different color, font etc. 
I tried to use appendParagraph, this works but it creates new paragraph with line break, i need the text in one line. Perhaps the solution would be to be able to join two paragraphs together and remove the line break but simple replace(/\n/g) is not working.

Please help how to solve this. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide the input and output samples you expect? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: Hi, the output should be like https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GVFfhxjUmEjvrsXJ7vNbPUFAf62Zi6D0/view?usp=sharing , the inputs as per my example, I have otherwise a long scrip reading them and parsing from google sheet.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand about your goal from your replying. This is due to my poor English skill. I apologize for this.